# Перекодировка из utf-8 без BOM в windows-1251

Tags: перекодировка

Имеется файл в кодировке utf-8 с текстом ТОЛЬКО на латинице. Пробую с помощью notepad++ перекодировать его в windows-1251. Сохраняю, открываю заново, но файл читается все равно в кодировке utf-8 (без BOM). Вопрос: как мне сделать, чтобы файл был в кодировке windows-1251, иначе его не может использовать одна программка. И как вообще любая программа, использующая файл, определяет его кодировку? Как например тот же notepad++ может понять кодировку, если все символы в нем на латинице, а их коды совпадают и в windows-1251 и utf-8?

Comment: @eicto в случае латиницы частотным анализом разделить cp1251 и utf8 сложновато:)

Я думаю, что notepad++ просто берет utf8 как более оптимальный вариант.

Comment: а каким тогда  образом мне заставить прогу видеть этот файл в кодировке windows-1251, не изменяя видимой контент? Просто у нас куплена прога и ей нужен файл именно в этой кодировке. Владелец проги прислал нам файл который сначала и был в windows-1251 и в нем были только латинские символы, но мы пересохранили этот файл, ничего не добавляя и теперь невозможно вернуть его опять в кодировку windows-1251

Comment: я бы взял любую утилиту, которая умеет сравнивать бинарные файлы (например - http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/). Дальше, взял исходный присланный файл, открыл его в редакторе и сохранил с новым именем (теперь он должен "поменять кодировку"). После это сделал бы сравнение. Подозреваю, что там есть парочка символов, которые и портят все.

Comment: @KoVadim если это текст на латинице без единого управляющего кода, то это не-utf (ну или utf, короче говоря его кодировка utf/latin-1 не имеет значения, так-же как невозможно сказать по начертанию , на каком именно языке написано "A" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно с чего Вы взяли, что в Вашем файле отсутствует BOM?

Если в файле текст ТОЛЬКО на латинице, то кодировки utf-8 и 1251 отличаются только наличием/отсутствием BOM'а.

Собственно то, что Вы написали про пересохранение, как раз очень похоже на добавление BOM'а.

Другой вопрос, что ни один редактор BOM Вам не отобразит. Есть некоторая надежда на редактор Far, но скорее всего и его будет не так то просто заставить отобразить эти символы.

В общем, Вам нужно удалить из файла первые два байта (ну или затереть их допустим пробелами), причем сделать это надо не в текстовом редакторе (ну или в редакторе, который не знает, что такое utf-8).

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander->F4-> В AikelPad Сохранить как-> Внизу выбрать имя,расширение и кодировку